# Highcharts - Hide subtitle on exporting

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart with time series and zoom. It will be better if the subtitle ("Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in") which is certainly very usefull in order to understand how to zoom don't appears when the chart is exported to pdf or image.

So I wonder if there is a way to hide it.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/PMyHQ/390/) on how to do what you are asking.  The part does the subtitle manipulation is:

```
exporting: {
   buttons: {
      exportButton: {
         menuItems: null,
         onclick: function() {
            chart.exportChart(null, {subtitle: {text:''}});
         }  
      },
      printButton: {
         onclick: function() {
            chart.setTitle(null, { text: ' ' });
            chart.print();
            chart.setTitle(null, { text: 'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' });
         }
      }
   }
},
```

**EDIT:**

**Sedondary option**

You could remove the Highcharts generated print and export buttons.  Then create your own print and export buttons along with a drop down for selecting the export type.  Then if the export button is clicked, check the type and export as the type and without the sub title.  Here is an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/348sh/3/).  Here is the code that handles the export and print button clicks:

```
$('#buttonExport').click(function() {
    var e = document.getElementById("ExportOption");
    var ExportAs = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;   

    if(ExportAs == 'PNG')
    {
        chart.exportChart({type: 'image/png', filename: 'my-png'}, {subtitle: {text:''}});
    }
    if(ExportAs == 'JPEG')
    {
        chart.exportChart({type: 'image/jpeg', filename: 'my-jpg'}, {subtitle: {text:''}});
    }
    if(ExportAs == 'PDF')
    {
        chart.exportChart({type: 'application/pdf', filename: 'my-pdf'}, {subtitle: {text:''}});
    }
    if(ExportAs == 'SVG')
    {
        chart.exportChart({type: 'image/svg+xml', filename: 'my-svg'}, {subtitle: {text:''}});
    }
}); 

$('#buttonPrint').click(function() {
     chart.setTitle(null, { text: ' ' });
     chart.print();
     chart.setTitle(null, { text: 'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'd like to keep the differents exporting options (PNG, JPEG, PDF, SVG). I tried this but It don't work: onclick: function() {
           this.exportChart(null, {subtitle: {text:''},type:"image/jpeg"});
          }

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how you can select the export type as well as remove the sub title.

Comment: Thank you again. Your solution is very usefull. Nevertheless, as I already have some custom buttons for other features, I would have preferred to use the existing buttons to avoid overloading my chart. I know I ask a lot :).

Answer (score 1):

I did another example keeping the subtitle if anyone have translations on their pages and want to print the chart. Just simply add a variable on the @Linger answer:

```
var subtitle = this.options.subtitle.text;
chart.setTitle(null, { text: ' ' });
        chart.print();
        chart.setTitle(null, { text: subtitle });
```

Example code here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/pb6tbx7u/